# Blocking UIWebView alerts

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, popup, alert

I have an app that opens webpages from a variety of domains. Some of those domains have embedded scripts that display alerts like `You're the 1 millionth visitor to this website. You won >>nothing<<"`.

I've decided to hijack `window.alert` method calls to do nothing so that no malicious alerts can be displayed by said websites.

I block the alerts in both `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType` and `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` to prevent websites displaying alerts before the page has finished loading.

Some crash reports indicate that calling `webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:...` from `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` causes the app to crash. Not always, just sometimes. Any idea why that might be?

Is there a way to prevent the alerts displaying in the first place without doing the manual hijacking? I'd love to use SFSafariViewController but that's not an option for various constraints unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use WKWebView?
WKWebView hooks JS's alert and do nothing by default.

FYI:

If you want to show alert when JS's alert is called, implement WKUIDelegate's

```
webView(webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo, completionHandler: () -> Void)
```

and show dialog by yourself.

Comment: Ah, didn't know WKWebView did that, that's actually really cool! That said, WKWebView is also a constraint I'm dealing with, so while your answer is helpful, I can't work with it.